# Why Linux syslog file does not follow the RFC3339 protocol?

Tags: timestamps, syslog, protocols

Why Linux syslog file: /var/log/syslog does not follow the timestamp format defined in the protocol https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424#page-11?

Comment: Historic reasons - the various syslog programs pre-date the RFC and log parsing programs might not recognize the different timestamp.  If you want the new format and you're running rsyslog you can set `$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_FileFormat` in rsyslog.conf

Comment: I think you are confusing network transmission of messages *intended for reciept* by syslog with syslog's own output, which is configurable and not, AFAIK, bound by any particular standard.

Comment: Thank you guys for helping me understand better this topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From RFC 5424 (which lays down the syslog protocol and refers to RFC 3339 for timestamps) *"1. Introduction"*:

> This document describes the standard format for syslog *messages* and
>   outlines the concept of transport mappings.  It also describes
>   structured data elements, which can be used to transmit easily
>   parseable, structured information, and allows for vendor extensions.
>
> **This document does not describe any storage format for syslog
>
>   messages.  It is beyond of the scope of the syslog protocol and is
>
>   unnecessary for system interoperability.**

A *message* here refers to *what is to be logged,* and NOT the *format of the logging.*  Put another way: the log is not the message, and the RFC is about the message, not the log.

The stuff you see in `/var/log/syslog` is the "stored format" messages.  That format is determined by how you have configured your particular syslog, and as the preamble states, there is no real necessity for any protocol there, at least as far as "system interoperability" goes.

Syslog daemons can serve as loggers for multiple systems.  The RFC is intended to set a standard such that compliant systems can log to a remote syslog, regardless of which particular implementation is in use, etc.

The syslog daemon receiving such messages will then write them to a file, but it doesn't write them verbatim -- it writes them in accordance with its configuration.  If you look at the RFC further, you will notice there are many, many ways in which `/var/log/syslog` does not comply.  Take a look at the [ABNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABNF) at the beginning of section 6 -- this does not simply describe a line in a log file (notice the timestamp is not nearly the first item!).  This is a structured format for [serializing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) messages for transmission.

Comment: @GreivinLópez if this answers your question, can you please mark it as accepted? Thanks